# Make the JSON string to be tree based after deserialization without the class

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON string

```
{"fields": "{\n  \"CurrentPage\": 14,\n  \"CurrentSubPageNo\": 18,\n  \"IsFileUpload\": false,\n  \"VisitedPages\": [\n    2,\n    3,\n    4,\n    6,\n    7,\n    8,\n    10,\n    11,\n    12,\n    13,\n    14\n  ]\n}"}
```

How can I make it to be like the following in C#?

```
{"fields":{"CurrentPage":14,"CurrentSubPageNo":18,"IsFileUpload":false,"VisitedPages":[2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14]}}
```

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` and I do not know on how to achieve like the above result

Please do take a note that the value inside `fields` can be dynamic (which the key and value inside it can be present or not), which is why deserialize to a class for the value inside `fields` is not an option for me

Anyone knows on how to do it?

Thank you very much

Comment: The value of `"fields"` was double-serialized.  Any chance you could fix the code that does it, and not double-serialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is reasonably simple:

- Deserialize to a `JObject`
- Fetch the value of `fields`, which should be a string
- Parse that as a `JObject`
- Set the value of `fields` to the parsed value
- Reserialize the `JObject` to a string

Sample code - lacking error handling, of course:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string originalJson = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
Console.WriteLine($"Original JSON: {originalJson}");

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(originalJson);
string fieldsJson = (string) obj["fields"];
JObject fieldsObj = JObject.Parse(fieldsJson);
obj["fields"] = fieldsObj;

string newJson = obj.ToString(Formatting.None);
Console.WriteLine($"New JSON: {newJson}");
```

Answer (score 1):

your "fields" property of json object is serialized twice, so you need just parse it twice. You can put all code  in one line

```
json = new JObject { ["fields"] = JObject.Parse(
 (string) JObject.Parse(json)["fields"])}.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```